# An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation - unknown tag

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm trying to generate the javadoc through maven by doing this `mvn javadoc:javadoc javadoc:aggregate` and [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi4rA.png)

Thats my function where the problem is:

```
/** Divide 2 int
* @param a int
* @param b int
* @return a / b if b != 0
* @throw IllegalArgumentException if b == 0
*/
public static int division(final int a, final int b) {
  if (b == 0) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("b must be equal to 0");
  }
  return a / b;
}
```

Thats not my code, it is for a school project.

Cordially

Comment: can you try `@throws`

Comment: Thanks, that was just that.. But I still ahve the other error about `@constructor`, maybe I just need to erase it ?

Comment: I'm not sure that tag `@constructor` exists.

Comment: Ok, i'll just erase it then, thanks dude !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreeing with the comments of @dehasi I additionally just want to point you to a **tag-specific** section of deeper explanation in an Oracle article about [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#tag).

It covers the well-known tags, their recommended order as well as cardinalities, semantics and if applicable their equivalent synonyms.